# Why wont console.SetOut(StreamWriter) write to my file?

Tags: c#, io, console-application, filestream, streamwriter

Creating a console app and I'm trying to set up a log file to keep track of the activities of my application.
This is how I'm setting up my FileStream and Writer.

```
FileStream logstrm;
StreamWriter logwriter;
logstrm = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
logwriter = new StreamWriter(logstrm);
```

Before calling SetOut, the following properly outputs the text to the console.

```
Console.WriteLine("LOG FILES CREATED");
```

However, once I do the following, I expect the text to be written to file.txt, but there is nothing in the file when I open it.

```
Console.SetOut(logwriter);
Console.WriteLine("TEXT EXPECTED TO BE IN FILE.TXT");
```

Any ideas or am I just doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Close Stream - logwriter.Close()

Comment: It is an infamous Unix problem, google "getta byte, getta byte byte byte" to get the Windows designer's opinion of the practice.  Little he could do about it.  It is up to you to set the StreamWriter.AutoFlush property to *true*.

Comment: Since `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` implement `IDisposable`, you should be declaring those with `using` blocks anyway. They'll automatically get closed/flushed when you're done with them.

Answer (score 1):

File I/O is buffered and may need to be flushed to actually write to the file.

You can explicitly flush to file by calling [StreamWriter.Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) ; alternatively you could set [AutoFlush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the stream is flushed after every call to Write.

Files are automatically flushed on [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't close the output file

```
logwriter.Close();
```

Either use Flush or Close the file

*PS: Another test: You can continue to write to console till you exceed the internal buffer size and then you will see that some chars are written to file*